# Http connexion errors with firefox 40

Tags: firefox, tcp

We are developing an http based application in flash, and all the users who updated firefox to 40 are experimenting the same issue : some http transfert does not seems to work correctly, or seems broken by the client. This can manifest with an incomplete XML, or connections errors.

We tried to monitor the network transmission, and saw a tcp FIN request from the client to the server, followed by a RST request (I can send the full dump if required) :

18           11:19:13.948144000        172.28.0.9           192.168.138.53  TCP        54           59456→panagolin-ident [FIN, ACK] Seq=533 Ack=15121 Win=16695 Len=0    59456,9021

21           11:19:13.949000000        172.28.0.9           192.168.138.53  TCP        54           59456→panagolin-ident [RST, ACK] Seq=534 Ack=16381 Win=0 Len=0              59456,9021

(192.168.138.53 is the server and 172.28.0.9 the client here)

The same connection with previous ff version do not show thoses error. We tried with different FF versions on the same PC and the issue is reproducible.

I did not found a similar problem on the web ; we need help to understand what is causing this issue. Is there is similar problem already referenced ? What are the information that you may need ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this matter by any means but I think the contents of the previous packets matter.

Comment: I've upload the full tcp dump (whireshark format) : 

http://elm-demos.elettermail.eu/elm-demos/livrables/wrong_tcp.pcapng
md5 : 63bd5e939bf73253205ba77fde8635b1

Comment: I think I have a few ideas, do you also have a pcap for older versions of firefox?

Comment: Yes, just let me some time to filter the dump and I sent you the trace.

Comment: This is the same exchange with ff : 39

http://elm-demos.elettermail.eu/elm-demos/livrables/ok_tcp.pcapng
md5 : e6d5609cc6ae4e23fe6404e28752e090

Comment: The only difference is TCP window scaling and it's what I was thinking in the first place. It has caused problems for me multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

try this at a client system:
linux:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0
```

windows:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

Comment: Thanks, we will try with this option.

But, as a developper, we can't ask each custommer to modify the system configuration…

We are trying it anyway.

Comment: This did not work, we got the same error.

I'll upload the pcap as soon as possible.

Comment: if this or similar options work you can do it programatically

Comment: With this option, the dump seems good, but the application still complains about a wrong data transmission.

After a lookup in the code, we saw that the same connexion is reused for many exchanges with the server, in a serial.

We are trying to change to code to use many connexions in parallel, but this does not explain the cause…

Comment: when flow rate changes windows goes crazy.it's just simple bad design by microsoft. everyone working with low-level tcp knows that.

Comment: What I do not undertstand is : why did this change between ff 39 and 40 ? We are testing on the same computer, with the same OS ; only firefox changes !

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report for this in mozilla : https://bugzil.la/1193393

The solution to set dom.ipc.plugins.asyncInit=false in about:config worked for us.